# React.Js Background Image properly displayed with words over the top

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, singlepage

I'm basically trying to copy this website as a lesson to teach myself React.

http://www.milkbardigital.com.au/#home

Could someone help me to use an image as background and place the text over it, also, how to make it display on the same amount of height on the page?

Here's my current code

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default React.createClass ( {
    render() {
        var background = {backgroundSize : 'cover'};
        return (
            <div style={{width: 'auto'}}>
                <Image style = {background} responsive src = "http://www.milkbardigital.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Milkbar-Home-Background.jpg">
                    This is a test
                </Image>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Can you please post `Image` component's code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are facing is that `Image` component is a void element tag and can't receive a children or a dangerouslySetInnerHTML function.

You will need to use CSS and a text (or div) element outside of the `Image` component, like the following:

```
var App = React.createClass ( {
    render() {
        var background = {backgroundSize : 'cover'};
        var textStyle = {
          position: 'absolute', 
          top: '50%', 
          left: '50%'
        };

        return (
            <div style={{width: 'auto'}}>
                <Image 
                  style={background} responsive 
                  src="http://www.milkbardigital.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Milkbar-Home-Background.jpg">
                </Image>
                <h1 style={textStyle}>Text over image</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Here is a sample demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/w1W8v3y8

Hope it helps!

Comment: Will try and use this, thanks so much though @Inacio

Comment: What is a void element tag?

Comment: Void element tags are tags that can't have any content inside. Here is the full list: https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#void-elements

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the help - was wondering why it wouldn't work!